# Calculus on Spaces other than $R$

Tags: calculus, soft-question, field-theory

I was thinking that all that the real numbers (and the complex numbers similarly) need for calculus to work is for them to be a field and a complete metric space, and probably have the usual field operations being continuous. From this it would seem that limits can make sense, and so you can have differentiation. Integration may be harder to define since it uses the ordering of $R$, but I'm sure it could be done (I don't know much about generalized integration).

Is this possible? Are there interesting fields which are also complete metric spaces and satisfy continuity of operations?

Comment: For integration, look at [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

Comment: Thanks, that would suit this idea perfectly for integration. I've never seen most of those things before, but it seems that a complete metric space is always locally compact, and being a field with continuous operations implies it is a topological group so this applies.

Comment: Well, you have the field $\mathbf Q_p$  of $p$-adic numbers, which is endowed with an *ultrametric* absolute value. Of course $p$-adic Analysis is very strange, as compared to classical analysis on $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$. For instance, a series converges if and only if its general term tends to $0$, an open ball is centred at any of its points, &c.